# Displaying data with ng-repeat from JSON array in angular

Tags: angularjs, arrays, json

Hi I have following data that is returned from service which I do not have any control on how it is returned:

```
{"day_1":[{"classroom":"Nursery","count":0},{"classroom":"Junior Kindy","count":1}],"day_2":[{"classroom":"Nursery","count":4},{"classroom":"Junior Kindy","count":0}]}
```

but I need to display it in pivot format that is like below:

```
classroom    | day_1  | day_2
============  ======== ======
Nursery      | 0      | 4
Junior Kindy | 1      | 0
```

This is the code in controller

```
$scope.rolls=[];

Rolls.getRollMarked().then(
    function(data){
        console.log(data.data);
        $scope.rolls = data.data;
    }
)
```

in the view I am using following but it doesn't display any count for the day and I am not sure how to display it..so please let me know how can I display it in the above format?

```
   <table class="table table-bordered">
      <tr>
         <td>Classroom</td>
         <td>day_1</td>
         <td>day_2</td>
       </tr>
       <tr ng-repeat="roll in rolls">
          <td> 
            {{roll[$index]['classroom']}}
          </td>
          <td>
              {{roll.day_1}}
               </td>
               <td>
                   {{roll.day_2}}
               </td>
            </tr>
     </table>
```

Comment: Your JSON data is not valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your data. `ng-repeat` as you have set it up expects an array.

Using some easy code you can get it to an array though, and then your code will work alright.

Also, you should update your html. You don't need to reference items using $index since each item is bound to the iterator variable in that case

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tr>
     <th>Classroom</th>
     <th>day_1</th>
     <th>day_2</th>
   </tr>
   <tr ng-repeat="roll in rolls">
      <td> 
        {{roll.classroom}}
      </td>
      <td>
        {{roll.day_1}}
      </td>
      <td>
        {{roll.day_2}}
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

And then call a convert function that makes the data into an array. I've used [lodash.find](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#find) here, so you either need to reference that or use your own find method.

```
Rolls.getRollMarked().then(
    function(data){
        console.log(data.data);
        $scope.rolls = convert(data.data);
    }
)

function convert(json) {
    var rolls = [];
    var days = ['day_1', 'day_2'];
    for (var d = 0; d < days.length; ++d) {
      var day = days[d];
      for (var i = 0; i < json[day].length; ++i) {
        var classroom = json[day][i];
        var existing = _.find(rolls, { "classroom": classroom.classroom });
        if (!existing) {
          existing = { classroom: classroom.classroom };
          rolls.push(existing);
        }
        existing[day] = classroom.count;
      }
    }
    return rolls;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know it could be done this way. +1 for find... Fantastic!!